# Read and parse specific parts of the file

Tags: c++

I have an input file with the following content:

```
Tstart: 13:51:45
Tend: 13:58:00
```

and I'd like to have the timestamps in separate strings at the end. So far, I've written the following:

```
// open the info file
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        // read the info regarding the played video
        string line;
        while (getline(infile, line))
        {
            istringstream iss(line);
            string token;
            while (iss >> token)
            {
                string tStart = token.substr(0, 6);
                string tEnd = token.substr(7,2);
                cout << tStart << tEnd<< endl;
            }

        }
        infile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "Video info file cannot be opened. Check the path." << endl;
```

and I get the following output:

```
Tstart
13:51:5
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 7) > this->size() (which is 5)
```

I do understand what the error says, but I cannot find another way of doing this in C++.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Why are you using `substr`?

Comment: You are not reading the file the way you intended it.  I suspect that you copied the code and not fully understand it.  The first token that you do `substr()` on is "Tstart:" if you showed the actual file.  A debugger will show you exactly what is being read.

Comment: @LogicStuff Because I want only the timestamps in the file, not the other pats. And that is a "substring" of the string in that file.

Comment: @stefaanv Huh? The code almost does what I intended to. I am trying to read the timestamps into their respective strings.

Comment: If your code was almost perfect, why did you accept the answer that presents a significant different approach?

Comment: I explained why. Why are you trying to hinder the question?

Comment: Added more code, so now everyone should be happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String `line` will be one line of text. First it will be "Tstart: 13:51:45", and in the next iteration it will be "Tend: 13:58:00".

String `token` will be part of the `line` that is delimited with space. So, if line is "Tstart: 13:51:45" then token will be "Tstart:" in first iteration and "13:51:45" in second iteration. This is not what you need.

Instead of the inner `while` loop I suggest searching for a space with `string::find` and then taking everything after the space with `string::substr`:

```
bool is_first_line = true;
string tStart, tEnd;

while (getline(infile, line))
{
    int space_index = line.find(' ');

    if (space_index != string::npos)
    {
        if (is_first_line)
            tStart = line.substr(space_index + 1);
        else
            tEnd = line.substr(space_index + 1);
    }

    is_first_line = false;
}

cout << tStart << tEnd << endl;
```

If it is not known in advance which line has which value then we can still get away from inner loop:

```
string tStart, tEnd;

while (getline(infile, line))
{
    int space_index = line.find(' ');

    if (space_index != string::npos)
    {
        string property_name = line.substr(0, space_index);

        if (property_name == "Tstart:")
            tStart = line.substr(space_index + 1);
        else if (property_name == "Tend:")
            tEnd = line.substr(space_index + 1);
    }
}

cout << tStart << tEnd << endl;
```

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. I was trying to do it without knowing which line is first and which is second, thought I wouldn't need it since in the while loop I read it in order anyway. But yes, I see now. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the second section of the post, that is exactly what I was trying to come up with!